# Blackberry : How to add external file in blackberry project and open it to device

Tags: blackberry

I am a newbie to blackberry app development and want to add an external file(image, doc etc) in blackberry project and after generating output file, when i install it to device my file where extracted to any location. It is possible? n how?
 plz somebody help me on it.

Comment: BB10 (C++/Cascades) or BB7 (Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article describes how to add a file as a resource to your BB project;

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Add-plain-text-or-binary-files-to-an-application/ta-p/445098

Copying it from there once your application is installed, is just a matter of using the FileConnection API.

The supplied SQL demo does something very like this for the SQL database, so I would look at that sample for more.

Comment: Thank You..!! Peter Strange.